# CGContextShowTextAtPoint and cyrillic text

Tags: objective-c, ios, xcode

I'm having a bit of a problem, drawing text on an image. When I'm trying to display English text, everything works just fine. The problem is, I need to localize text. When text is Russian, some strange symbols are shown. Any help would be appreciated.

I'm using following code, to draw text:

```
CGContextSetRGBFillColor(context, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 1);
char* text = (char *)[addText cStringUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding];
CGContextSelectFont(context, "Impact", 20, kCGEncodingMacRoman);
CGContextSetTextDrawingMode(context, kCGTextFill);
CGContextShowTextAtPoint(context, 20, h+addHeightBelow, text, strlen(text));
```

And it shows following:

[image: Ruined text]

So in result, you should use Core Text, and the code is:

```
CTFontRef fontRef=CTFontCreateWithName((CFStringRef)@"Impact", 20.0f, NULL);
CGColorRef color=[UIColor blackColor].CGColor;
NSDictionary *attrDictionary=[NSDictionary dictionaryWithObjectsAndKeys: 
                              (id)fontRef, (id)kCTFontAttributeName, 
                              color, (id)kCTForegroundColorAttributeName,
                              nil];
NSAttributedString *stringToDraw=[[NSAttributedString alloc] initWithString:addText attributes:attrDictionary];

CTLineRef line=CTLineCreateWithAttributedString((CFAttributedStringRef)stringToDraw);
CGContextSetTextPosition(context, 20, h+addHeightBelow);
CTLineDraw(line, context);

CFRelease(line);
CFRelease(fontRef);
[stringToDraw release];
```

Comment: The answers to this question might be useful.
 http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6461980/how-to-display-international-accents-with-quartz-core-graphics-on-iphone

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use [**Core Text**](http://www.cocoanetics.com/2011/01/befriending-core-text/) for drawing localized text on an image. Refer [this](http://www.ultrajoke.net/2011/08/quick-tip-drawing-core-text-right-side-up/) for sample